# how to convert a dataframe to a list and write to file

Tags: r, list, bioconductor

I am trying to extract information from bioconductor GO database, but am having problems exporting data I can use for further processing and analysis.

I have a list of 24 affyIDs (called sig) and access the database as such:

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("mouse4302.db")
library("mouse4302.db")
GO=as.list(mouse4302GO)
```

Ideally I would like the file output to be written as:

```
x
1415670_at.GO:0016192.GOID  GO:0016192
1415670_at.GO:0016192.Evidence  IEA
1415670_at.GO:0016192.Ontology  BP
```

...

but am having issues getting beyond the first few elements to be written with this

```
write.table(unlist(GO[sig[1:13]]), file='b.txt',sep='\t',row.names=T,quote=F)
```

going beyond the 13th element does not work and print out

```
x
1   GO:0001701
2   IMP
3   BP
4   GO:0006499
5   IMP
6   BP
....
```

This is from

```
write.table(unlist(GO[sig[1:14]]), file='b.txt',sep='\t',row.names=T,quote=F)
```

Any ideas, help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Alex

Comment: what is your `sig` variable ?

Comment: If you don't pass a data.frame or matrix to `write.table`, it tries to coerce the input to a data.frame before writing. Have a look at `as.data.frame(unlist(GO[sig[1:14]]))`.

Comment: Hans: sig variable is a list of affyIDs

Comment: Roland: unfortunately that does not work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Might as well ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/). Remember to load the library

```
library(mouse4302.db)
```

and make sure your R is not too old (The result of my `R.version.string` is "R version 3.0.2 Patched (2014-01-02 r64626)").

One approach is to use the `select` interface on these data bases

```
## discovery
keytypes(mouse4302.db)      ## how to query
columns(mouse4302.db)       ## what to retrieve
```

here are some ids.

```
eid <- head(keys(mouse4302.db, keytype="PROBEID"))
```

and the GO identifiers associated with those ids, returned as a simple data.frame

```
xx <- select(mouse4302.db, eid, "GO", keytype="PROBEID")
```

Here we write out the data

```
write.table(xx, file=tempfile(), sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, quote=TRUE)
```

Here's an [introductory workflow](http://bioconductor.org/help/workflows/annotation/annotation/) for working with annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the link Martin, unfortunately when applying the function select I get      Error: could not find function "select"

Comment: @alex -- I added a couple of hints -- make sure you are using a relatively recent R, and that you have loaded the library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies, but I managed with the following code:

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("mouse4302.db")
library("mouse4302.db")
x=mouse4302GO
write.table(links(x[sig]), file='b.txt',sep='\t',row.names=F,quote=F)
```

Again, sig is a list of AffyIDs.
My table ends up:

```
probe_id    go_id   Evidence
1415670_at  GO:0016192  IEA
1415670_at  GO:0006810  IEA
1415670_at  GO:0006886  IEA
1415670_at  GO:0015031  IEA
1415671_at  GO:0006810  IEA
```

And this is great fr further analysis!